# Compare each string in datatable with that of list takes longer time.poor performance

Tags: linq, list, optimization, compare, query-performance

I have a `datatable` of 200,000 rows and want to validate each row with that of list and return that string `codesList`..
It is taking very long time..I want to improve the performance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    bool isCodeValid = CheckIfValidCode(codevar, codesList,out CodesCount);
}

private bool CheckIfValidCode(string codevar, List<Codes> codesList, out int count)
{
    List<Codes> tempcodes=  codesList.Where(code => code.StdCode.Equals(codevar)).ToList();
    if (tempcodes.Count == 0)
    {
        RetVal = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            bool isCodeValid = CheckIfValidCode(codevar, codesList,out CodesCount);
        }
    }
}

private bool CheckIfValidCode(string codevar, List<Codes> codesList, out int count)
{
    List<Codes> tempcodes=  codesList.Where(code => code.StdCode.Equals(codevar)).ToList();
    if (tempcodes.Count == 0)
    {
        RetVal = false;
    }
    else
    {
        RetVal=true;
    }
    return bRetVal;
}
```

`codelist` is a list which also contains 200000 records. Please suggest. I used `findAll` which takes same time and also used LINQ query which also takes same time.

Comment: For each row (200.000 rows) you have 200.000 "codelist"?? There are 40.000.000.000 of checks.. How long is "very long time" ??

Comment: yes right..To compare just 5k records it will take 2.2 mins.

Answer (score 0):

A few optimizations come to mind:

- You could start by removing the `Tolist()` altogether
- replace the `Count()` with `.Any()`, which returns true if there are items in the result
- It's probably also a lot faster when you replace the List with a `HashSet<Codes>` (this requires your Codes class to implement HashCode and Equals properly. Alternatively you could populate a `HashSet<string>` with the contents of `Codes.StdCode`
- It looks like you're not using the `out count` at all. Removing it would make this method a lot faster. Computing a count requires you to check all codes.
- You could also split the List into a Dictionary> which you populate with by taking the first character of the code. That would reduce the number of codes to check drastically, since you can exclude 95% of the codes by their first character.
- Tell `string.Equals` to use a `StringComparison` of type `Ordinal` or `OrdinalIgnoreCase` to speed up the comparison.

It looks like you can stop processing a lot earlier as well, the use of `.Any` takes care of that in the second method. A similar construct can be used in the first, instead of using `for` and looping through each row, you could short-circuit after the first failure is found (unless this code is incomplete and you mark each row as invalid individually).

---

Something like:

```
private bool CheckIfValidCode(string codevar, List<Codes> codesList)
{
    Hashset<string> codes = new Hashset(codesList.Select(c ==> code.StdCode));

    return codes.Contains(codevar);
    // or: return codes.Any(c => string.Equals(codevar, c, StringComparison.Ordinal);
}
```

If you're adamant about the count:

```
private bool CheckIfValidCode(string codevar, List<Codes> codesList, out int count)
{
    Hashset<string> codes = new Hashset(codesList.Select(c ==> code.StdCode));

    count = codes.Count(codevar);
    // or: count = codes.Count(c => string.Equals(codevar, c, StringComparison.Ordinal);

    return count > 0;
}
```

You can optimize further by creating the HashSet outside of the call and re-use the instance:

```
InCallingCode
{
   ...
   Hashset<string> codes = new Hashset(codesList.Select(c ==> code.StdCode));

   for (/*loop*/) {
       bool isValid = CheckIfValidCode(codevar, codes, out int count) 
   }
   ....
}


private bool CheckIfValidCode(string codevar, List<Codes> codesList, out int count)
{
    count = codes.Count(codevar);
    // or: count = codes.Count(c => string.Equals(codevar, c, StringComparison.Ordinal);

    return count > 0;
}
```